# How do I redirect unauthenticated visitor on my extended Django Admin page?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I've added a new path `admin/testing/` on project's `urls.py` like this

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
...
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('admin/testing/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='admin/testing/testing.html')),
...
```

and also `testing.html` on `my_app/templates/admin/testing/testing.html`, but I am able visit `admin/testing/` without login first. On `testing.html` I've a got a form there, only when I submit the form then it will prompt an alert to ask me to enter my username and password.

```
<!-- testing.html -->
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/dashboard.css" %}" />{% endblock %}

{% block coltype %}colMS{% endblock %}

{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} dashboard{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="content-main">
        <div id="testing-root"></div>

        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/babel">
            class AdminTesting extends React.Component {
                ...
                render() {
                    const { state } = this;
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h2>Transform Users Play Count into Ratings</h2>
                            <form>
                                Weight:<br/>
                                <input
                                    type="number"
                                    step={0.1}
                                    name="transformWeight"
                                    value={state.transformWeight}
                                    onChange={this.handleChangeFraction}
                                /><br/>
                                <input style={styles.btn} type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleRatingTransformation} />
                                { state.transformLoading && 'Please wait ...' }
                            </form>
                            ...
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }
            ...
            ReactDOM.render(
                <AdminTesting/>,
                document.getElementById('testing-root'),
            );
        </script>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Edit:

```
class TemplateView(TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin, View):
    """
    Render a template. Pass keyword arguments from the URLconf to the context.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the decorator to limit the access

staff_member_required is a good decorator for you needs .
please refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/decorators/) for more info

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

path('admin/testing/', staff_member_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='admin/testing/testing.html')))
```

Comment: it didn't work, I'm still able to visit without authenticate

Comment: can you check whether you are authenticated or not ?? can you print request.user in the extended admin template and paste it here ?

Comment: somehow, it won't print anything, I've added `print(self.request.user)` on `TemplateView.get`

Comment: can you print it on template ?? like {{request.user}}

Comment: I don't know what happened, but now your solution has redirected me to the login page when I try to access `admin/testing/`, so I enter my credentials and it redirect me to `admin/testing/`, but when I try to submit my form, it ask for credentials again

Comment: Good but not perfect though, I wonder why did it ask me for credentials again when I was authenticated in order to access the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177010/discussion-between-edwin-harly-and-nakul-narayanan).

Answer (score 1):

In your `urls.py` you are using `TemplateView` which is from **`django.views.generic.base.TemplateView`**. But it should be from your corresponding `views.py`, the place where it's defined by you.

apart from that, use [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) to do an authentication as,

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView # remove this import
from .views import TemplateView # import "TemplateView" from your "views.py"

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('admin/testing/', login_required(
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='admin/testing/testing.html'), login_url='/admin/')),
]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work out. And you might be misplaced one of your parantheses I'm afraid.

Comment: can you add `TemplateView` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by adding `TemplateView' ?

Comment: the view class you are mentioned in urls.py?

Comment: Oh, it's Django's TemplateView I import from `django.views.generic.base`

Comment: just add your views.py, to question, not as comment

Comment: I've updated the answer, and corrected the parathesis also

Comment: I just noticed that the url has changed to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/testing/admin/?next=/admin/testing/`, I guess the correct one should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/testing/` ?

Comment: Change **`login_url='admin/`** to **`login_url='/admin/`** (add a slash to the beginning of `admin`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177009/discussion-between-edwin-harly-and-jerin-peter-george).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `TemplateView`:

```
class TemplateView(TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin, View):
    """
    Render a template. Pass keyword arguments from the URLconf to the context.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return render(request, 'target.html')
            #target is where you want the unauthorized logger
        else:
            context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: TemplateView is not written by myself, but I import it from `django.views.generic.base`, and I don't think modifying it is a good idea